# if else on javascript with the value of a select box (pure javascript)

Tags: javascript, onchange, selectedindex

I'm working on a select box that have images instead of text, (on the background with css).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onChange(element) {
element.style.backgroundColor = "Yellow";
element.className = "on_change";
}
</script>



<select onchange="onChange(this);">
<option value="1" style="background: url(/one.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; width:32px; height:32px;"></option>
<option value="2" style="background: url(/two.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; width:32px; height:32px;"></option>
<option value="3" style="background: url(/three.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; width:32px; height:32px;"></option>
</select>
```

The problem is how do I get the value of the selected option and if is 1 set one image and if it is two set another image as the background using pure javascript (no jQuery)?

I know that `selectedIndex` is the key to my problem, but I'm clueless of how to use it or how to use it on an `if else` statement.

The script above is just one of my trials, I actually use the script above to perform the same task.

```
<select onchange="this.style.backgroundColor=this.options[this.selectedIndex].style.backgroundColor; this.style.color=this.options[this.selectedIndex].style.color">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working example. http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpb9

you dont need if else but just change background image based on selectedIndex.

```
function onChange(obj) {
    obj.style.backgroundImage = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].style.backgroundImage
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, just one thing, the image gets repeated so I replaced `backgroundImage` with `background` It's that correct ?

Comment: .background will work no issues.  but i would suggest you write CSS so you for no-repeat. like   "  select, select option {background-repeat:no-repeat; } "   and have only background-image in style tag. so you have little bit cleaner mark up

Comment: Greaat!!! Unfortunately I just find out that it will not work on IE so now trying to find a solution

Comment: In IE you can style select box as its attached to system component. you can only few basic properties like bgcolor, height, width font related etc. so you need to look for converting the <select to so div based layout.

Comment: typing mistake. In IE you can NOT style select box extensively as its attached to system component. ........